# Displaying an array of values via foreach loop and how can I limit the array to be displayed?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to know how can I limit the values of array to be displayed. Assuming my `$color` is equals to `Indigo`

I tried implementing this code by it doesn't work

```
foreach($data as $item){
    if($item['color'] == $color){
        echo $item['size'].'-'.$item['color'].'-'.$item['price'].'<br>';
    }
}
```

And if I remove the `if statement` the `var_dump($data)`

```
    array(16) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["size"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["price"]=>
    string(6) "$59.00"
    ["color"]=>
    string(11) "Black Rinse"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["size"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["price"]=>
    string(6) "$59.00"
    ["color"]=>
    string(6) "Indigo"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["size"]=>
    string(1) "4"
    ["price"]=>
    string(6) "$59.00"
    ["color"]=>
    string(11) "Black Rinse"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(3) {
    ["size"]=>
    string(1) "4"
    ["price"]=>
    string(6) "$59.00"
    ["color"]=>
    string(6) "Indigo"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(3) {
    ["size"]=>
    string(1) "6"
    ["price"]=>
    string(6) "$59.00"
    ["color"]=>
    string(11) "Black Rinse"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(3) {
    ["size"]=>
    string(1) "6"
    ["price"]=>
    string(6) "$59.00"
    ["color"]=>
    string(6) "Indigo"
  }
  [6]=>
  array(3) {
    ["size"]=>
    string(1) "8"
    ["price"]=>
    string(6) "$59.00"
    ["color"]=>
    string(11) "Black Rinse"
  }
  [7]=>
  array(3) {
    ["size"]=>
    string(1) "8"
    ["price"]=>
    string(6) "$59.00"
    ["color"]=>
    string(6) "Indigo"
  }
  [8]=>
  array(3) {
    ["size"]=>
    string(2) "10"
    ["price"]=>
    string(6) "$59.00"
    ["color"]=>
    string(11) "Black Rinse"
  }
  [9]=>
  array(3) {
    ["size"]=>
    string(2) "10"
    ["price"]=>
    string(6) "$59.00"
    ["color"]=>
    string(6) "Indigo"
  }
  [10]=>
  array(3) {
    ["size"]=>
    string(2) "12"
    ["price"]=>
    string(6) "$59.00"
    ["color"]=>
    string(11) "Black Rinse"
  }
  [11]=>
  array(3) {
    ["size"]=>
    string(2) "12"
    ["price"]=>
    string(6) "$59.00"
    ["color"]=>
    string(6) "Indigo"
  }
  [12]=>
  array(3) {
    ["size"]=>
    string(2) "14"
    ["price"]=>
    string(6) "$59.00"
    ["color"]=>
    string(11) "Black Rinse"
  }
  [13]=>
  array(3) {
    ["size"]=>
    string(2) "14"
    ["price"]=>
    string(6) "$59.00"
    ["color"]=>
    string(6) "Indigo"
  }
  [14]=>
  array(3) {
    ["size"]=>
    string(2) "16"
    ["price"]=>
    string(6) "$59.00"
    ["color"]=>
    string(11) "Black Rinse"
  }
  [15]=>
  array(3) {
    ["size"]=>
    string(2) "16"
    ["price"]=>
    string(6) "$59.00"
    ["color"]=>
    string(6) "Indigo"
  }
}
```

I want only to display values which is the color is equal to `$color`. How should I do this the correct way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be dealing with case sensitivity or white space .. you can try :

```
$data = array(
        0 => array("size" => "2","price" => "$59.00","color" => "Black Rinse"),
        1 => array("size" => "2","price" => "$59.00","color" => "Indigo"));


$color = "Indigo";
foreach ( $data as $item ) {
    if (strtolower($item['color']) == strtolower($color)) {
        echo $item['size'] . '-' . $item['color'] . '-' . $item['price'] . '<br>';
    }
}
```

Output

```
2-Indigo-$59.00
```

[See Live Demo](http://codepad.org/6ydarHe4)

Comment: can you `var_dump($data)` like to see what am dealing with

Answer (score 1):

This should fix your issue (assuming you're comparing two strings, I suggest you use strcasecmp- for case insensitive string comparison in your if loop)

```
foreach($data as $item){
    if(strcasecmp(trim($item['color']),trim($color))==0){
        echo $item['size'].'-'.$item['color'].'-'.$item['price'].'<br>';
    }
}
```

Comment: and what is the exact value of $item['color'] ?

Comment: It depends..because it is base on user input.

Comment: Works perfectly for me as well with the above code, see http://codepad.org/sgeVhEDw

Answer (score 1):

Be elegant, be simple:

```
    $items = array(
        array('size'=>'4', 'color'=>'Indigo', 'price'=>'$59.00'), 
        array('size'=>'5', 'color'=>'black', 'price'=>'$59.00'), 
        array('size'=>'5', 'color'=>'green', 'price'=>'$54.00'),
        array('size'=>'7', 'color'=>'Indigo', 'price'=>'$50.00'),
        array('size'=>'5', 'color'=>'purple', 'price'=>'$51.00'));

   print_r(array_filter($items, function($i){
          return in_array('Indigo', $i);
      })
   );
```

or PHP < 5.3:

```
print_r(array_filter($items, 
    create_function('$i', 'return in_array("Indigo", $i);'))
);
```

Take advantage of features that PHP offers.